How to decode ASP.NET Core 8 Identity token on the client side?
ASP.NET Core 8 Identity produces a token that is NOT JWT!

The tokens aren't standard JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). The use of custom tokens is intentional, as the built-in Identity API is meant primarily for simple scenarios.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-token-based-authentication

The question is how to decode the Identity token on the client-side to get the username, claims, etc. out of it, like what we always do with JWTs.

Hi @Tohid, you can check the source code here to know how to decrypt the token to a byte array  and convert this byte array to base64string in the server. Then decode base64string by atob() function in the client side.

Thank you @Rena for the tip. I'm still trying to figure it out.

As @Rena mentioned, you can attempt to decipher the token, but it won't contain username or claims as standard JWT. As you quoted docs in your question, this is intended for simple scenarios, so the token contains only timestamp, user ID, purpose and security stamp, as can be seen here. For more advanced usage, you probably need a more dedicated approach.
